# Einstein Analytics on External objects

Tags: einstein-analytics, externalobjects

Can Salesforce Einstein Analytics be sourced on External objects and external data source

Comment: Have a look at [Einstein Analytics trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/wave_analytics_basics), it will answer your question